# How do i set attributes on a single option of a CheckboxSelectMultiple ChoiceWidget generated by a ManyToMany field in a form in django?

Tags: django

I have a django app with multiple choice questions and answers. The unanswered answers are stored as BooleanFields in a database table and rendered as a form to be answered by the user.

When the user has answered the multiple choice question, the question with the given answers is to be displayed again to show if each single multiple choice option was correct or incorrect answered.

Thus, we need to set an attribute on each of the widgets which get automatically generated by the default widget renderer when the ManyToMany related field of the model class is evaluated during form rendering, which we in turn want to access in the remplate to properly style the output html to give visual feedback to the user.

models.py

```
from django.db import models
...
class SchulungsEinheitTestergebnis(models.Model):
    """ Schattentabelle eines Testergebnisses einer Frage eines Schulungseinheittestes """
    id                   = models.AutoField('ID', primary_key=True, db_column='sete_id')
    schulungseinheittest = models.ForeignKey(SchulungsEinheitTest, db_column='set_id', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, default=None, blank=True)
    frage                = models.ForeignKey(Frage, db_column='frg_id', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, default=None, blank=True)
    antworten            = models.ManyToManyField(Antwort, blank=True, help_text='Gegebene Antworten', related_name='set_set',related_query_name='set', verbose_name='Gegebene Antworten (Nur für Fragen mit Mehrfachauswahl)')

    def is_richtig(self):
        if not self.frage:
            return False
        richtige_antworten = self.frage.antwort_set.filter(richtig=True)
        gegebene_antworten = self.antworten.all()
        if not len(gegebene_antworten) == len(richtige_antworten):
            return False
        not_found = False
        for richtige_antwort in richtige_antworten:
            if richtige_antwort not in gegebene_antworten:
                not_found = True
        return not not_found
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from django.forms.widgets import CheckboxSelectMultiple    

class TestErgebnisFormMehrfach(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = SchulungsEinheitTestergebnis
        fields = ('id',  'frage', 'antworten')

        widgets = {
            'frage': FrageWidget,
            'antworten': CheckboxSelectMultiple
        }

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(TestErgebnisFormMehrfach, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if self.instance:
            if self.instance.frage:
                self.fields['antworten'].queryset = self.instance.frage.antwort_set.all()

class TestErgebnisFormMehrfachErgebnis(TestErgebnisFormMehrfach):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(TestErgebnisFormMehrfachErgebnis, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['antworten'].disabled = True
```

test.html

```
{% for form in formset %}
  <div >
    {{ form.id }}
    <div class="zustand">
      <p class="fragen-nummer">Frage {{ forloop.counter }}</p>
    </div>
    <div class="inhalt">
      <p class="fragetext">{{ form.frage }}</p>
      <div class="antworten mehrfach">
    {% for radio in form.antworten %}
        <div class="antwort">
          {{ radio.tag }}
          {# here i need access to some information tagged to the "radio", or to the displayed answer instance #}
          <label class="knopf" for="{{ radio.id_for_label }}"></label>
          <label class="antworttext" for="{{ radio.id_for_label }}">{{ radio.choice_label }}</label>
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
{% endfor %}
```

The actual checkboxes are automatically generated when the default widget renderer finds a CheckboxSelectMultiple widget.

The corresponding field has a queryset attached to show only the answers related to the question.

The question is: do i need to implemement my own widget renderer, or is there a way to provide the default widget renderer the information it needs to tag the generated checkboxes with some attributes so it can be accessed during template rendering ? radio.is_correct_answered in the above template code for example.

How to accomplish this ?

Comment: where do you store the information ,  if the choice selected by user was right or wrong?

Comment: I have edited the question to show more details.

Comment: not able to understand the meaning of variable and model names. I guess they are from a non-english language. If my understanding is correct "Antwort" stores the answers given by the user. Add a boolean field in "Antwort" , which will record status if it is a right or wrong answer. use that field in template to change CSS attribute.

Comment: The checkboxes for the Many-To-Many field "antworten" of the model class "SchulungsEinheitTestergebnis" are generated on the fly by the default widget renderer when the form "TestergebnisFormMehrfach" is rendered. 


The queryset is restricted to show only answers related to the question. I can not see a way how to get any instance information into the process of rendering checkbox widgets automatically shown by use of a many-to-many field in a form class.